# Force Close in Landscape Mode, but not in Portrait

Tags: android, button, listactivity, screen-orientation, android-orientation

I have an application which shows a list of items in runtime. When the user presses a `Button`, all selected items should be deleted (selection determined by `CheckBox`). In *portrait* mode everything works well, but when I switch to landscape mode **when the number of rows are more than 3**, pressing the delete button gets the `Force Close Exception` and I am unable to print the stack trace. **When there are 3 or less rows it works perfectly!** 
I've written the layout for both `layout` (portrait) and `layout-land` directories. Code and Layouts are as follows:

Here is the handler for Delete Button:

```
   Button DeleteGoods=(Button)findViewById(R.id.DeleteSelectedGoodsButton);
   DeleteGoods.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckBox cbx = (CheckBox)listView.findViewById(R.id.ChkOrder);
            int firstPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                for (int i = firstPosition; i < listView.getCount(); i++) {

                    View v1 = listView.getChildAt(i);

                    cbx = (CheckBox)v1.findViewById(R.id.ChkOrder);
                    if(cbx.isChecked())
                        checkedItemPosition=i;                  
                }
                try {

                    DeleteCheckedItem(checkedItemPosition);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"The selected order has been deleted successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    finish();
                    startActivity(getIntent());
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


        }

    });
```

Here is the layout in landscape mode:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#000000" >
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/DeleteSelectedGoodsButton"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:text="@string/DeleteSelectedGoods"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/ConfirmDelete"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:text="@string/ConfirmDeleteButton"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/CancelButton"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:text="@string/CancelButton"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/aa"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/CancelButton" />

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/GOODNAME_CELL"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:text="Order"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/aa"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
         <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/GOODUNITPRICE_CELL"
            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:text="Unit Price"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/aa"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/GOODNAME_CELL" />
         <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/QUANTITYCELL"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:text="Quantity"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/aa"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/GOODUNITPRICE_CELL" />
         <ListView 
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/CodeFont"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/GOODUNITPRICE_CELL" />

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TotalPriceTextview"
            android:layout_width="600dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is the exception I am getting:

```
02-19 10:07:11.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4335): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-19 10:07:11.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4335): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-19 10:07:11.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at com.example.nfc.PrepopSqliteDbActivity$1.onClick(PrepopSqliteDbActivity.java:117)
02-19 10:07:11.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2552)
02-19 10:07:11.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9229)
02-19 10:07:11.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-19 10:07:11.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-19 10:07:11.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:138)
02-19 10:07:11.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
02-19 10:07:11.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-19 10:07:11.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-19 10:07:11.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
02-19 10:07:11.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
02-19 10:07:11.398: E/AndroidRuntime(4335):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-19 10:07:11.408: W/ActivityManager(1768):   Force finishing activity com.example.nfc/.PrepopSqliteDbActivity
02-19 10:07:11.909: W/ActivityManager(1768): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{40b2ed78 com.example.nfc/.PrepopSqliteDbActivity}
02-19 10:07:16.353: I/InputDispatcher(1768): Application is not responding: Window{40a73e60 com.example.nfc/com.example.nfc.PrepopSqliteDbActivity paused=false}.  5004.7ms since event, 5004.4ms since wait started
02-19 10:07:16.353: I/InputDispatcher(1768): Dropping event because the pointer is not down.
02-19 10:07:16.353: I/InputDispatcher(1768): Dropping event because the pointer is not down.
02-19 10:07:16.353: I/WindowManager(1768): Input event dispatching timed out sending to com.example.nfc/com.example.nfc.PrepopSqliteDbActivity
02-19 10:07:16.353: I/ActivityManager(1768): Crashing app skipping ANR: ProcessRecord{40a1b188 4335:com.example.nfc/10003} keyDispatchingTimedOut
02-19 10:07:21.428: W/ActivityManager(1768): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
02-19 10:07:21.908: W/ActivityManager(1768): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{40a1b7d8 com.example.nfc/.Buy}
02-19 10:07:26.963: I/touchd(1518): 'ab8500_usb' is online
02-19 10:07:26.963: I/touchd(1518): handling_uevent: event is 1
```

**Edit**

This is line 117:

```
DeleteCheckedItem(checkedItemPosition);
```

and this is the method's body:

```
private void DeleteCheckedItem(int chkPosition)
{   
    String strName=goods.get(chkPosition).get(GOOD_NAME);
    String strPrice=goods.get(chkPosition).get(GOOD_UNITPRICE);
    String strQuantity=goods.get(chkPosition).get(QUANTITY);
    String whereClause = "GOOD_NAME = ? AND GOOD_UNITPRICE= ? AND QUANTITY= ?";
    String[] whereArgs = {strName,strPrice,strQuantity};
    database.delete(TABLE_NAME, whereClause, whereArgs);
}
```

Comment: Post the logcat trace too. Sometimes it could be as trivial as a character out of place. ;-)

Comment: I get this exception on my cellphone not on the emulator,because my database is empty and is being filled at runtime when I install it on my phone,and my cellphone does not work well  unfortunately when I want to run the app in usb debugging mode!do you have any idea?Please give me a suggestion.Thanks

Comment: Post the logcat trace. Lets see where the crash occurs.

Comment: I put the logcat in my question

Comment: Your problem is a `NullPointerException ` on line 117 of `com.example.nfc.PrepopSqliteDbActivity` in the `onClick` method.

Comment: I know,but how should I handle this exception!?

Comment: How is `checkedItemPosition` declared? How is it initialized? Note that it's possible that in the code you show in your question that it hasn't received any value (i.e. none of the items are checked).

Answer (score 4):

Is `checkedItemPosition` an `int` or an `Integer`?

My guess is its an `Integer` that was initialized to `null`.

When you rotate, the activity is recreated and your `checkedItemPosition` was reinitialized to `null`.

Then you enter your for-loop, but none of the `Checkbox` views were checked so your `checkedItemPosition` is still `null`.

You try to call `DeleteItemChecked` on a `null` while it expects a primitive `int` and voila: `NullPointerException`.

Solution: initialize `checkedItemPosition` to `0`.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this kind of problem. My theory is related to the observation of Shadi

Portrait mode can display more rows than in landscape mode. And since you iterate the listview item count and try to get the view on the said position. If the view or item of the listview is not visible in the window/phone screen. There is possibility that you can get null values. getView() method of an adapter is called every scrolling, since initialization or recreating listview items is in getView() without proper calling in getView() method items that are not visible in window/phone screen is not initialized. You can use the method in listview: [getLastVisiblePosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getLastVisiblePosition%28%29) to limit the number of item you will iterate to the listview.

Hope this will help you. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like either `database` or `TABLE_NAME` is *null*. Add these lines before line 117 to test:

```
if (strName == null)
    Log.w("Test", "strName is NULL");
if (strPrice == null)
    Log.w("Test", "strPrice is NULL");
if (strQuantity == null)
    Log.w("Test", "strQuantity is NULL");
if (TABLE_NAME == null)
    Log.w("Test", "TABLE_NAME is NULL");
if (whereClause == null)
    Log.w("Test", "whereClause is NULL. WTF!");
if (whereArgs == null)
    Log.w("Test", "whereArgs is NULL. WTF!");
if (database == null)
    Log.w("Test", "database is NULL");
```

Comment: So why it works perfectly in portrait mode and also landscape mode for 3 or less than 3 number of items!?

Comment: @ShadiS, Well, what does the `logcat` print when you add these lines?

Answer (score 0):

Got the problem and the solution is as below. when you rotate the screen the Adapter is getting initialized again and the previous array is getting cleaned. what you can do is put the `onConfigurationChange()` in the activity and try to check the output.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, what happens if delete is pressed but nothing is checked?

Getting to your question, is it possible that the checked item is not visible once delete is pressed? If so, because of View recycling (a scary, if clever, thing), it might not actually exist when you get to the delete button code, so you need to be careful about querying views at that point. It might be wiser to build up a "current selected list" as selections are made (and unmade) so that when delete is pressed you no longer have to query any views.

As an aside, it also looks like it will only delete the first checked item, but I may have missed something there.

Answer (score -1):

Have you specified the handling of config changes in the Manifest file, if not please do so by adding: `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation` to your activity.

Please paste logcat, that will provide more info.. Good luck..

Comment: I'm new in android!I get this exception on my cellphone not on the emulator,because my database is empty and is being filled at runtime when I install it on my phone,and my cellphone does not work well unfortunately when I want to run the app in usb debugging mode!do you have any idea?Please give me a suggestion.Thanks .I'm checking the manifest now

Comment: Few mobile devices require relevant software driver for the USB mode to work with your PC/Laptop. Look for those on the device manufacturers website. After you connect the device in USB debugging mode from the "device : settings > Developer Options", you can check the logcat. If you use Eclipse IDE: Go to Window > ShowView> Logcat

Comment: Actually my device s Xperia Sola and I have downloaded the software an it is running on my pc but when I want to press the buttons or type something in the application which I run and the usb port is connected none of the buttons work well and they get mixed up for example instead of "s" it types "p"!Thanks for your care

Comment: I put the logcat in my question

Comment: Have you made the changes in the manifest as suggested? And what is on  line 117 in PrepopSqliteDbActivity, is it the onClick() method?

Comment: Here is the code between line 115 until 119                         ` View v1=listView.getChildAt(i);
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Getting the row "+v1.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 cbx = (CheckBox)v1.findViewById(R.id.ChkOrder);
  if(cbx.isChecked())`

Comment: The problem seems to be something else, if they work in portrait, they will work in landscape too, as the code is not different for each. Remove the Toast message, and let me know the exact code in the line number again. And this time set the orientation only to landscape by adding this to manifest 'android:screenOrientation="landscape"' This is only to test if there is something at all in landscape mode that is causing it.

Comment: I've changed the manifest but when i open this activity I runtime again I get the exception!Please help me to solve this issue,I need to have both orientation modes in this app!Please check my question for the edited part.

Comment: Does the app crash on launch itself in Landscape mode? Also please paste the complete logcat, especially the lines after `Causesd By:`  it seems the problem is more specific to the methodDeleteCheckedItem(checkedItemPosition); but we need to find out which line in this method is causing the issue.

Comment: No ,when I press the Delete Button it crashes.I've pasted the logcat in this link http://pastebin.com/9mtEa9qP                     please check it

Comment: Can you delete the Landscape file, and run the app. If it works, then you have some problem with the layout itself.

Comment: Please also paste you manifest file code where you have added the `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation` add this to each of the activities.

Comment: It's still crashing when the number of rows are more than 3!Even when I deleted the landscape layout

Comment: So the problem is not with Landscape or Portrait mode, there is something else in the code that is crashing. It seems that the UI is trying to populate the value that is non existent. Please check the effects of DeleteCheckedItem() method, what exactly are you doing after this action? Your DB has 1 record deleted, what next? are you populating the listview again from the DB or using the earlier retrieved list to populate?

Comment: In your onClick() code, you are calling  `finish();` before `startActivity();` . Somehow the flow does not seem right, the checkboxes are multiple choice right? How are you storing the multiple deletion records indexes in 1 variable `checkedItemPosition`. Your try - catch should be inside the loop and do not finish() the activity and also just start the loop from 0 instead of `listView.getFirstVisiblePosition()`.

Comment: Now when I put the try catch inside the loop in the landscape mode I still get the exception and also it deletes another item in the list!It's really odd!

Comment: Yes,but it didn't work!It's really weird!It works perfectly in portrait mode without any exceptions or errors!